# Free timestamped audio transcription (speech to text)?

Tags: speech-recognition

Is there any free service/program that will transcribe audio to text 
and preserve timestamps?

I want to transcribe:

[This is the demo link of VoiceBase](http://www.voicebase.com/voice_file/public_detail/258709)

(a 16m conversation between 419 scammers; the scammers speak with 
heavy accents, so I'm not complaining about the quality of the 
transcription).

Voicebase DOES transcribe it, but the transcription is a single block 
of test, and is not timestamped.

I also tried the Google voice "trick" (record the file into voicemail 
and have Google transcribe it 3 minutes at a time), but, again, the 
transcription is a single block of text, not timestampped.

I am aware of Sphinx, but couldn't get it to work.

I realize I could use subtitleeditor to create a manual trascription, 
but I'm looking for an automated solution.

Ideally, I'd like to take a timestamped machine transcription and hand edit it.

Comment: CMUSphinx can transcribe this file just fine with even higher accuracy than Voicebase. You are welcome to give a link on the file itself, and I'll provide you the example timestamps and transcription.

Comment: Thanks! If the URL in the post doesn't work, try http://s3.amazonaws.com/plivocloud/4c743546-7e1b-11e2-9060-002590662312.mp3 (if it works, I'll make more of an effort to get sphinx working on my own machine and/or befriend you <G>)

Comment: Sorry for delay, I've added you the example below.

Comment: @barrycarter that is a hilarious conversation! From where did you get it?

Comment: http://wordpress.barrycarter.info/index.php/2013/03/22/long-conversation-between-scammers/ 
has more details, and 
https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/419 tells more about 
the project. https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/SOUND 
has other automated transcriptions of this call.

Comment: Speechlogger = Google's speech + timestamps. See my detailed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMUSphinx can do this, just run Aligner demo from the sources. The latest sphinx4 tutorial is available [in sphinx4 tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4). In the summer 2014 CMUSphinx has integrated [long audio alignment](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2014/07/long-audio-aligner-landed-in-trunk/) functionality in sphinx4 trunk.

It is totally wrong but unlike voicebase it captured at least some words. Probably it's easier to transcribe it manually and later assign times. CMUSphinx can also do this with audio-to-text alignment.

There are quite many issues with decoding accuracy caused by accents and shorttalk, but there are things you are responsible for too. For example you should never convert telephone audio of 8khz bandwith to mp3. Such conversion drastically reduces the accuracy of the automated speech recognition and the overall recording quality. You could use other speech-oriented lossless codecs for compression.

Other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983925/create-subtitles-for-audio-books/34989464#34989464) discussing the subject, listing some recommendations.

Comment: Thanks, Nikolay! The file comes directly from plivo.com, so I don't
think I have a choice of format. I went ahead and manually created an
.srt file for the first 3 minutes of this recording and also uploaded 
the Google Voice transcriptions for these 3 minutes 
(https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/tree/master/SOUND). I will use 
your data to create an SRT file to compare to mine.

Comment: Ok, great. Ask if you need more help.

Comment: If you're OK with talking via email/Google Talk, I'm carter.barry@gmail.com -- I can chew your (virtual) ear off for days ;)

Comment: Sure, my gmail is nshmyrev@gmail.com, you can also find me in #cmusphinx irc channel on freenode

Comment: Hey there Nikolay! The above dropbox link now 404s, would it be possible to reinstate it (or at least give a more complete description of the process taken here) for posterity? I've stumbled across this question with almost the exact same requirements as Barry, and it'd be great to see how you did this.

Comment: Hi. The latest sphinx example could be found here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/26073448/test.tar.gz, is not online, please reupload, tnks

Comment: See the update in the end of an answer

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev good day; I cannot download sphinx to python with the last MacOS Big Sur update. I've tried pip, pip3, homebrew. Nothing works. What can be done?  Are you aware of this problem or is it an individual case?

Answer (score 0):

While Searching in Google you will get a long list of transcription software that is powered by market professionals.Some of examples are:

1. Express Scribe
2. EureScribe
3. InqScribe

But the problem occurred while using automated software is that it does not provide the exact results which we need. So If you still getting any issues in using these software, then you can hire a transcribe to ease your work.

Answer (score 0):

A new software (chrome web-app) named Speechlogger (https://speechlogger.appspot.com) was made exactly for that purpose. It preserves timestamps, and lets you export to [srt (captions) format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#SubRip_.28.srt.29_structure_examples).

It is supposed to be the best technology out there as it utilizes Google's speech recognition engine. 
It also auto-punctuates (based on simple words content and structure).