# Create timestamps for subtitles in audibook

Tags: audio, speech, levenshtein-distance

I want to add timestamps to book sentences, fitting the relevant audiobook.
In various languages ideally.

**Here's an example:**
*Pride and prejudice*
[text from gutenberg project](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1342/pg1342.txt)
[audio from Librivox](http://ia700408.us.archive.org/8/items/pride_prejudice_1102_librivox/prideandprejudice_01_austen_64kb.mp3)

My idea was to find a voice recognition tool that puts timestamps on sentences (step 1), and then map the messy transcription to the original text using levenshtein distances (step 2).

The website https://speechlogger.appspot.com/ offers a solution to the 1st step, but it's limited in character output. I could theoritically use web automation to get the job done, by starting a new recording every minute or so, but it's really dirty.

I scripted step 2 in R and tested it on a sample I got from speechlogger and it works okayish, but this could be greatly improved if the program knew the text, like when you read to train a speech recognition software. I'm not using all my information here by transcribing first.

So my questions are, what alternative ways could i have to timestamp audio files, and is there a way i can make my process smarter by letting the recognition engine know what it's supposed to recognize ?

Comment: Moody Mudskipper, I wonder if you can provide me with an Android app, please look at [this post]( http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/52769/45942) to see what I am looking for. Any suggestions? Many, Many Thanks.

Comment: What you are trying to create is what I called "Audio-eBooks", which contain the text and the audio, in sync. Have a look at https://www.readbeyond.it/ , where you can also find aeneas, a forced aligner that works well for that kind of application, in 30+ languages.

Comment: This looks amazing Alberto, thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many nice software packages developed for that with various level of accuracy:

[Gentle](https://github.com/lowerquality/gentle) - Kaldi-based aligner, works as a service.

Older implementations:

[Aligner Demo in Sphinx4](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-samples/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/aligner/AlignerDemo.java) - CMUSphinx toolkit in java

[SAIL align](https://github.com/nassosoassos/sail_align) - HTK-based aligner, quite some pack of perl scripts.

Comment: Many thanks, it seems that "forced alignment" was really the keyword I needed.