# Word indexing in audiofile when the text is known

Tags: python, pattern-matching, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I have an audio file and a text file which correspond to what is said in the audio. Is their a way with Python (using any library) to find the start timestamp (and eventually end) of each word in the audio.

For example, if I have an audio file and a text file which contains "Hello, my name is" (corresponding to what is said in the audio), I want to obtain something like that :

```
"Hello" : 1'24.038 -> 1'24.321    
"my" : 1'24.518 -> 1'24.627    
"name" : 1'24.629 -> 1'24.851    
"is" : 1'24.861 -> 1'24.921
```

I realize that speech recognition is a really hard problem, but my problem seems a lot easier since it just consists in matching text and audio. However, I still haven't find any way to do it, and if there exists nothing easy, does anybody have an idea of how I could start ? Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create subtitles for audio books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983925/create-subtitles-for-audio-books)

Answer (score 3):

[aeneas](https://www.readbeyond.it/aeneas/docs/index.html) does that very well. Pretty robust in my experience. Only drawback it that it seems to be way better at finding the beginning of the words that the end. So basically you will have:

```
"Hello" : 1'24.038 -> 1'24.518 
"my" : 1'24.518 ->  1'24.629   
"name" : 1'24.629 -> 1'24.861    
"is" : 1'24.861 -> 1'24.921
```

Give it a try!

Comment: The lead dev of aeneas here: thank you for mentioning aeneas! Dear OP: please note that aeneas was not design to work at word-level, however it can be used at word-level (in fact, several users do). If you care to take a look at the aeneas mailing list, you can find some tips&tricks. If you give it a try, and need help, feel free to post on the aeneas mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *forced audio alignment*. The problem is easy as long as the audio duration is relatively short, and can be solved with the most of speech recognition frameworks. However, the problem [becomes trickier](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/longaudioalignment) when the audio is long. There are no known out-of-the-box solutions for Python, so you will have to call binaries from the code.

Comment: Actually, besides aeneas mentioned in the other answer, there are a few forced aligners (mostly relying on HTK or Kaldi) written in Python. I compiled a list here: https://github.com/pettarin/forced-alignment-tools